# Sublime Text 2 TM_FILEPATH regex snippet

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to make CodeIgniter CRUD snippet for Sublime Text 2 and I can't figure out how to write regex snipet, which will return specific part of the TM_FILEPATH variable

I found this one in one of the CodeIgniter snippets:

`${TM_FILEPATH/.+((?:application).+)/$1/:application/controllers/${1/(.+)/\l$1.php/}}`

If the file location is for example:

`/D/Web/MyApp/application/controllers/admin/user.php`

This snippet will return:

`application/controllers/admin/user.php`

What I need is only the part after "controllers" and without extension, in this example:

`admin/user`

PS: The path after controllers can have various number of directories, it can be `user` or also `admin/something/user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
${TM_FILEPATH/.+(?:controllers\/)(.+)\.\w+/PATH\l$1/}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer but this is returning `PATH/admin/test` for file located in `controllers/admin/test`. I removed the `PATH` from your regex, now it's returning `/admin/test`. Is there a way to remove the first slash?

Comment: awesome, i'ts working! I'm not sure why the word "PATH" is in the expresion, because the "PATH" is the in the result too, but when I remove it, it's working. Thank You!